# AMD R9 200X drivers

Tags: graphic-drivers

I have attempted to install AMD drivers 2 different ways

Both options via software & updates

Each time on reboot I'm faced with the splash screen e logo hanging

Running latest freya

Hardware:
LG 34" 34UM95-P @ 3440x1440 & AMD 290X 4GB

Any insight would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

**Installing via the command line**: From this [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD)

- Save a backup copy of xorg.conf in case this doesn't work.

  ```
  sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.BAK
  ```
- Remove/purge current fglrx and fglrx-amdcccle (If you have used a method outside of aptitude, apt, Software Center or Synaptic, follow the other party's instructions for removal).

  ```
  sudo apt-get purge fglrx*
  ```
- reboot
- fglrx-amdcccle is included when you install fglrx, so the following will suffice:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install fglrx
  ```
- To install the packages for hardware acceleration along with the driver:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install fglrx xvba-va-driver libva-glx1 libva-egl1 vainfo
  ```
- Generate a fresh xorg.conf BEFORE REBOOTING!

  ```
  sudo amdconfig --initial
  ```

Comment: how? please add commands

Comment: Please stop posting commands in comments. edit answer and add commands :)

Comment: Sorry new to this format of posting

Comment: I have edited and added info  for you :)